# javascript decimal (16 lower bits) to decimal

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal, bit

Sorry but i'm not good at bit conversion.
I need to convert decimal -> decimal by lower 16 bit, as this sample.

```
1:16777237 decimal = 1000015 hex
2:16 lower bits = 0015 hex (each digit in hexadecimal is 4 bits)
3: 0015 hex = 21 decimal  (21 is the result i need)
```

Using

```
(16777237).toString(16);
```

i can get the 1000015 hex, my question is how, i get the lower bits as im, not that strong in bits. etc. the bedst way to get the result.

Comment: Search for `javascript bitwise operation`, you will then be better in bits ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply a bitmask with 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub> and get the result with [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND).

```
              base 2             base 10   base 16
    -------------------------   --------   -------
    1000000000000000000010101   16777237   1000015
&   0000000001111111111111111      65535      ffff
-----------------------------   --------   -------
    0000000000000000000010101         21        15
```

```js
console.log(16777237 & ((1 << 16) - 1));
```

Another solution could be, just to use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) `%` with 2<sup>16</sup>.

```js
console.log(16777237 % (1 << 16));
```

Comment: Thanks, that perfect, could you also provide a sample on converting it back ? ^^ :)
21- > 16777237 
Thanks ! :)